# How to measure network contention

Tags: raspberry-pi, 3g

I have rasberry pi with a 3G shield connected to it. Is there a way to gather metrics about the network such as available data capacity/throughput, latency and way to measure contention on the network?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to know the statistics for your connection to the internet.

There is a great `Command-Line` tool for this by **sivel** which you can install from the command line using:

```
sudo pip install speedtest-cli
```

or

```
sudo easy_install speedtest-cli
```

and then just run it with the command:

```
speedtest-cli
```

and it will give you the results.

For more information please see the project page on GitHub:  https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli